# How to preserve spaces between words when outputting result in Сaesar cipher?

Tags: python

Text - "how are you"

Step - 5

Actual result - mtbfwjdtz

Desired result - mtb fwj dtz

How to keep spaces?

```
user_text = input('Please enter any text -> ')
user_number = int(input('Please, enter any integer -> '))

upper_alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
              'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
              ]
lower_alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
             'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
              ]
ciphertext = []

for letter in user_text:
    if letter in upper_alphabet:
        index = upper_alphabet.index(letter)
        new_index = (index + user_number) % 26
        new_letter = upper_alphabet[new_index]
        ciphertext.append(new_letter)
    elif letter in lower_alphabet:
        index = lower_alphabet.index(letter)
        new_index = (index + user_number) % 26
        new_letter = lower_alphabet[new_index]
        ciphertext.append(new_letter)

print(f"Ciphertext -> {''.join(ciphertext) }")
```

Comment: Think about it - what do you want to do if the letter isn't in either of those lists.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand the question. I just started learning python and there is still a lot that is difficult for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using and solving it using your example:

```
user_text = input('Please enter any text -> ')
user_number = int(input('Please, enter any integer -> '))
upper_alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
              'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
              ]
lower_alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
             'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
              ]
ciphertext = []

for word in user_text.split():
    temp = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in upper_alphabet:
            index = upper_alphabet.index(letter)
            new_index = (index + user_number) % 26
            new_letter = upper_alphabet[new_index]
            temp.append(new_letter)
        elif letter in lower_alphabet:
            index = lower_alphabet.index(letter)
            new_index = (index + user_number) % 26
            new_letter = lower_alphabet[new_index]
            temp.append(new_letter)
    ciphertext.append(''.join(temp))

print(f"Ciphertext -> {' '.join(ciphertext) }")
```

Result:

```
Please enter any text -> How are you
Please, enter any integer -> 5
Ciphertext -> Mtb fwj dtz
```

But as stated by `jonrsharpe` you should consider what will happen if you enter text that is not in the alphabet, for instance, if I enter `?` or `!` then it will not be processed.

You could also use the string library to get all printable characters:

```
import string
user_text = input('Please enter any text -> ')
user_number = int(input('Please, enter any integer -> '))
characters = string.printable # 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ♂♀
ciphertext = []

for word in user_text.split():
    temp = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in characters:
            index = characters.index(letter)
            new_index = (index + user_number) % len(characters)
            new_letter = characters[new_index]
            temp.append(new_letter)
    ciphertext.append(''.join(temp))

print(f"Ciphertext -> {' '.join(ciphertext) }")
```

Result:

```
Please enter any text -> How are you?
Please, enter any integer -> 5
Ciphertext -> MtB fwj Dtz^
```

This, however, still doesn't prevent someone from entering text that is not in the list of characters.

Comment: Thank you very much - user56700. If I enter a character that is not in the list, I use try - except. I understand how to eliminate the error, it just wasn’t in the condition of the assignment, so I didn’t do it.
I also, like you, pointed out that you do not need to enter the alphabet with your hands, but generate it. But we haven't learned libraries yet, so I didn't know how to do it without using 'import string'

Comment: @glaurungSCH We all started learning from nothing. If you like my answer feel free to accept it by clicking the V sign. :)